# Integration solution needed

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to solve the following integration $$\int_0^{\infty}\exp \left(-ax^4-bx^2[\pi/2-\arctan(\frac{c}{x^2d})]\right)dx$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are all constants and $\geq 0$. I know the following formula $$\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-ax-bx^2)dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}\exp(\frac{a^2}{4b})Q(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2b}})$$ where $Q(x)$ is the famous Q function. But I can not apply this formula because the form in my first equation does not matches exactly with the form of my second equation (because of the presence of $\arctan(\frac{c}{x^2d})$). How can I solve this problem? Is there any approximation of $\arctan()$ that can be used to make the form of my first equation look like the second equation. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you sure you want the $x^2$ multiplies the $\arctan$ term ? then it doesn't have a closed-form for sure

Comment: @user1952009 yes $x^2$ does multiply with the $\arctan(\frac{c}{x^2d})$ term. As can be seen in my second equation the answer is not a closed form (because $Q$ function has to be found numerically). In a similar way I want to know if there is any other known function which can be used in representing the answer just as $Q$ function is used for lower equation. Any comments on this?

Comment: $\displaystyle \arctan(x) = \frac{i}{2} \left[ \ln \left( 1 -ix \right) -  \ln \left( 1 +ix \right)\right]$  You can try to get the arctan out of the exp but it will still be ugly. Then use Hermite quadrature

Comment: @arthur after applying the $\arctan(x)$ value as you mentioned I have obtained following form of the integral $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax^4}e^{-bx^2\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[\frac{x^2d-ic}{x^2d+ic}\right]^{\frac{ibx^2}{2}}dx$. I do not know how to apply the Hermite quadrature. Please help me in this regard. Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature
$$ . $$
Its an even function so set up the integration limits:
$$\int_0^\infty f(x^2) dx = \frac1{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x^2) dx$$

$$-ax^4 - b\frac{\pi}{2}x^2 = -a\left(x^4 + \frac{b}{a}\frac{\pi}{2}x^2\right) = 
-a \left[ \left(x^2 +  \frac{b}{a}\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2 - \left( \frac{b}{a}\frac{\pi}{4} \right)^2 \right]$$

let $u = \sqrt{a}\left(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ find $dx$ in terms of $u$ then write the integral in the Hermite form

Comment: $$ \frac1{2} e^{\left(\frac{b^2\pi^2}{16a}\right)} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2} F(u) du$$

Note the $\frac{ibx^2}{2}$ power will cause oscillations impacting the number of points required for an accurate calculation.